# jQuery doesn't work for dynamic elements but works fine in console

Tags: jquery, dynamic, instagram

I am using plugin which displays images from Instagram on my website. When I try to apply jQuery (any jQuery i.e `$('.instagram_gallery').css('display', 'none')`) for any element, created by plugin, it works in console, but not in the code. I understand that jQuery doesn't see this code untill DOM is loaded. But the problem is none of the solutions are working - I tried both `$(document).ready(function() {})` and `$(window).on('load', function(){})`.

You can see plugin on this website (Instagram gallery section): 10oz.ru/mlight

The file with settings, where I am trying to add jQuery:

```
    <?php
class shopInstafeedPlugin extends shopPlugin
{    public static function display()
    {
        $plugin = wa('shop')->getPlugin('instafeed');
        $settings = $plugin->getSettings();
        $settings_json = json_encode($plugin->getSettings());
        $root = $plugin->getPluginStaticUrl();
        $html = <<<HTML
        <div id='instafeed'></div>
        <script src="{$root}js/jquery.instagramFeed.min.js"></script> 
        <script>
             (function($){
                $(window).on('load', function(){
                    $.instagramFeed($settings_json); 
             });
             })(jQuery);   
        </script>
<style>
HTML;
        if (!$settings['styling']) {
            $html .= $settings['css'];
        }
        return $html;
    }
}
```

So finally this code worked for me:

```
var settings = $settings_json;
    var callback = {callback: function (data){
       $('.instagram_gallery').hide();                
    }};
    jQuery.extend(settings, callback);
    (function($){
        $(window).on('load', function() {
            $.instagramFeed(settings);
        });
    }) 
    (jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in that you need to run your code *after* the new images have been added to the DOM. Assuming from your description you're using [this jQuery Instagram library](https://www.sowecms.com/demos/jquery.instagramFeed/index.html), then you can use the `callback` property to achieve this:

```html
<script src="{$root}js/jquery.instagramFeed.min.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery($ => {
    $.instagramFeed({
      callback: () => {
        $('.instagram_gallery').hide(); // note use of hide() instead of css()
      },
      // your other settings in this object...
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the plugin I use. Could you please help me to add settings from json to your construction, how it should look like? 

`<script> 
jQuery($ => {
$.instagramFeed({ 
callback: () => { 
$('.instagram_gallery').hide(); // note use of hide() instead of css() }, 
($settings_json) }); 
}); </script>`